# Android after starting native application, all process die

Tags: android, android-activity, process, native

After starting my native activity using Horde3D engine it loads resources, then the following log comes. At the end of the log it also indicates that my application has died and returns to the main screen. I'm using the native_activity_glue and the customized sample represented in the NDK.

```
01-03 16:04:23.696: D/StatusBar.NetworkController(1051): refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
01-03 16:04:24.177: I/QCNEJ(726): |CORE:COM:RCVR| CNE creating socket
01-03 16:04:24.697: D/StatusBar.NetworkController(1051): refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
01-03 16:04:24.947: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.facebook.katana:providers (pid 2428) has died.
01-03 16:04:24.997: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.apps.plus (pid 1237) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.007: D/WifiNative-wlan0(726): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
01-03 16:04:25.107: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.music (pid 860) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.198: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.joelapenna.foursquared (pid 1634) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.238: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.apps.uploader (pid 2197) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.268: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.gsf.login (pid 1791) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.298: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.idd.agent (pid 2172) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.328: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.androidapp.storefront (pid 2733) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.358: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.metago.astro:remote (pid 2944) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.388: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonymobile.cameracommon (pid 2747) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.408: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.android.keychain (pid 2760) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.438: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonymobile.tvout.wifidisplay (pid 2126) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.458: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 2986) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.468: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.android.defcontainer (pid 2686) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.528: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.updatecenter (pid 2786) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.548: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.android.remotecontrolservice (pid 2799) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.578: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.svox.pico (pid 2968) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.598: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.facebook.katana:dash (pid 1359) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.698: D/StatusBar.NetworkController(1051): refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
01-03 16:04:25.748: I/ActivityManager(726): Process android.process.acore (pid 1184) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.878: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.android.vending (pid 1307) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.908: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonymobile.social.services (pid 1156) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.948: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.android.musicfx (pid 2773) has died.
01-03 16:04:25.968: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.apps.magazines (pid 3096) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.018: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.talk (pid 2815) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.048: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonymobile.xperialink (pid 3049) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.088: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonymobile.mx.android (pid 2566) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.158: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search (pid 1468) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.219: I/ActivityManager(726): Start proc com.android.vending for service com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.services.ContentSyncService: pid=3170 uid=10093 gids={50093, 3003, 1015, 1028}
01-03 16:04:26.299: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.gms (pid 1347) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.339: D/Finsky(3170): [1] FinskyApp.onCreate: Initializing network with DFE https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/
01-03 16:04:26.339: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.album (pid 2898) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.369: D/Finsky(3170): [1] DailyHygiene.goMakeHygieneIfDirty: No need to run daily hygiene.
01-03 16:04:26.379: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sony.nfx.app.sfrc (pid 3068) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.389: W/Settings(3170): Setting download_manager_max_bytes_over_mobile has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
01-03 16:04:26.389: W/Settings(3170): Setting download_manager_recommended_max_bytes_over_mobile has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
01-03 16:04:26.389: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.google.android.youtube (pid 2217) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.469: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware (pid 2851) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.479: D/Finsky(3170): [1] 2.run: Loaded library for account: [NLDGMkMIs8WD4jrwJe7DmYvQzxA]
01-03 16:04:26.479: D/Finsky(3170): [1] 2.run: Finished loading 1 libraries.
01-03 16:04:26.489: D/Finsky(3170): [1] GmsCoreHelper.cleanupNlp: result=false type=4
01-03 16:04:26.529: D/Finsky(3170): [1] RestoreTracker.stopServiceIfDone: Restore complete with 0 success and 0 failed.
01-03 16:04:26.679: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.facebook.katana (pid 1482) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.679: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.push.mqtt.MqttPushService in 5000ms
01-03 16:04:26.679: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.metago.astro (pid 1503) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.869: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.facebook.orca (pid 1099) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.869: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.push.mqtt.MqttPushService in 14810ms
01-03 16:04:26.979: D/Finsky(3170): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
01-03 16:04:26.979: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sony.smallapp.managerservice (pid 1738) has died.
01-03 16:04:26.979: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sony.smallapp.managerservice/.SmallAppManagerService in 24696ms
01-03 16:04:27.009: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.android.vending (pid 3170) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.049: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.usbux (pid 2053) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.049: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.usbux/.service.UsbService in 24623ms
01-03 16:04:27.139: I/WindowState(726): WIN DEATH: Window{43666d18 u0 com.sonyericsson.home/com.sonyericsson.home.HomeActivity}
01-03 16:04:27.139: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.home (pid 799) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.350: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.advancedwidget.clock:lockscreen (pid 1684) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.350: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.advancedwidget.clock/com.sonymobile.lockscreenclock.ClockService in 24331ms
01-03 16:04:27.420: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.android.locationbasedwifi:service (pid 1438) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.420: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.android.locationbasedwifi/.LbwService in 34259ms
01-03 16:04:27.450: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonymobile.phoneusage (pid 2543) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.450: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonymobile.phoneusage/.service.DeviceUsageService in 44225ms
01-03 16:04:27.490: I/ActivityManager(726): Process android.process.media (pid 901) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.490: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonymobile.storagechecker/.controller.DeviceStorageService in 44182ms
01-03 16:04:27.490: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.providers.media/.MtpService in 44182ms
01-03 16:04:27.540: I/ActivityManager(726): Process com.sonyericsson.dlna (pid 939) has died.
01-03 16:04:27.540: D/WifiNative-wlan0(726): doBoolean: DRIVER RXFILTER-STOP
01-03 16:04:27.540: D/WifiNative-wlan0(726): doBoolean: DRIVER RXFILTER-REMOVE 2
01-03 16:04:27.540: E/WifiService(726): Multicaster binderDied
01-03 16:04:27.540: W/ActivityManager(726): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.dlna/com.sony.huey.dlna.UpnpServiceCp in 54133ms
01-03 16:04:27.550: D/WifiNative-wlan0(726): doBoolean: DRIVER RXFILTER-START
```

Comment: Not much there. Can you add more logs, before the problem happens. A wild guess: the app may be asking for tons of memory, forcing Android to reclaim resources (killing other apps). Check your memory allocations. If there is any place with huge allocations, comment it out for a test.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell from the log, but I suspect it is because of memory. Android will kill background applications when memory gets too low and that can also cause your app to crash. Perhaps there are more messages earlier that might be relevant?

I might try to start your app without loading a bunch of resources to see if other processes remain alive. (I assume you're loading a bunch of textures, etc.) That would tell you if the other process deaths are due to low memory.

Also, try querying available memory in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've measured the memory usage and it doesn't exceed (according to the Horde3D stats) 26 megabytes - the available memory in my phone is 2 GBs. If I load everything but doesn't call the update() routine, then the other processes don't crash, however only thing I see is black screen. Even if I start calling update it doesn't crash on the first cycle but after a while, and using only logging is really difficult to find out what dominates the phone. Any advice how should I move on? There are no useful messages before everything dies sadly.

Comment: Need to be able to start identifying differences between what works and doesn't. Have you been able to get any Horde3D app/sample to work at all? If those work, then start looking at the differences between your app and that one.